# Create Closed-Captions like YouTube

Tags: python, youtube, automation, subtitle, closed-captions

I have some videos and I want to create closed-Captions(cc) for theme.
Two ways have come to my mind:

1. use some libraries like [autosub](https://github.com/agermanidis/autosub) to generate subtitles.(i try it!it's very inaccurate way and full of bad translations!)
2. upload each video to youtube and let it to generate cc for you.(it is a boring process and you have to upload each video one by one!)
   I want an appropriate way to do it offline.like [autosub](https://github.com/agermanidis/autosub).is it exists any Library or Api to use youtube translation mechanism?
   Thanks.